# Custom Rewrite Rule for Custom Post Type with URL Param

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am trying to create a custom rewrite rule for a custom post type where

**This:**

```
http://test.loc/products/directory/?c=some-value
```

Should become **this**:

```
http://test.loc/products/directory/some-value
```

**Minimal code:**

```
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
      ),
      'show_ui' => false,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array("slug" => "products/directory")
    )
  );
  add_rewrite_rule( 
      '^products/directory/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$',
      'index.php?post_type=acme_product&c=$1',
      'top'
  );
}
```

I also tried like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 
    '^products/directory/?([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?post_type=acme_product&c=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

I simply can't get the value of **'c'**. Is there something in the rewrite rule that should be different? I can't seem to get this to work.

By the way I CAN retrieve 'some-value' of 'c' from this:

```
 http://test.loc/index.php?post_type=acme_product&c=some-value
```

To retrieve the value in the template I tried both:

```
get_query_var( 'c' );
```

and

```
$_GET['c'];
```

I get nothing back...

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:**

I am answering my own question here since no responses were given and I presume this might be helpful to someone and in the mean while I found a solution..

I had to use the second version of 'add_rewrite_rule':

```
add_rewrite_rule( 
  '^products/directory/?([^/]*)/?',
  'index.php?post_type=acme_product&c=$matches[1]',
  'top'
);
```

I needed to register a query var,, since external query params aren't recognizable to WordPress

```
function 123wp_query_vars( $query_vars ){
  $query_vars[] = 'c';
  return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', '123wp_query_vars' );
```

Then retrieve the value in the template using:

```
get_query_var( 'c' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a redirect with regex, use Yoast SEO and select Redirects and choose option Regex.

For a url go from `http://example.com/products/?c=some-value` to `http://example.com/products/some-value` use this regex expression and paste on Yoast redirect regex page:

> **Type:** 301 Moved Permanently
> **Regex Expression:** products/?c=/?([^/]*)/?
> **URL:** products/$1

I hope it helps another people who wants to redirect not just **add and rewrite_rule**

Best,

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Thank you for contributing. However, (bad news), GRowing appears to be asking about working with the re-write rules directly. While sometimes, yes plugins already do what we are trying to do, this is a WordPress development QnA and, generally, plugin recommendations are off-topic. If you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.